# extjs 4 : get store record values

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, store

my json data looks like this :

```
({"success": "true", "message" : "OK","data":[{"id_metric":"1","name_filter":"doc filter","type_guicomp":"combobox"},{"id_metric":"1","name_filter":"severity","type_guicomp":"combobox"}]})
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the `"type_guicomp"` field value for the `"id_metric" = 1` , so the result would be : `"type_guicomp":"combobox"` and `"type_guicomp":"combobox"`.

I do this because I need the value `"combobox"` to assign it to a variable.
I've tried several things including :

```
myStore.load({
        scope: this,
        callback : function(record, operation, success) {
            console.log(record);
            console.log(record.data);
            }
```

And :

```
var index = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("myStore").findExact('id_metric',1);
var rec = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("myStore").getAt(index);
console.log(rec);
```

These solutions return undefined or null.
So when I did this in the callback :

```
var i = myStore.getCount();
console.log(i);
```

It returned `0`. But when I check the json output, it's not empty and there's actually data in it.

What am I doing wrong? Please any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

My store looks like this :

```
Ext.define('Metrics.store.MyStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'Metrics.model.MyModel',
autoLoad: true,
idProperty: 'id_metric',
proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    actionMethods : 'POST',
    node : 'id_metric',
    api : {
    read : 'gui_comp_items.php' //the php script that gets data from db
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        successProperty: 'success',
        messageProperty: 'message',
        root: 'data'
    }
}
});
```

My Model :

```
Ext.define('Metrics.model.MyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
{name : 'id_metric', type : 'int'},
{name : 'name_filter', type : 'string'},
{name : 'type_guicomp', type : 'string'},
{name : 'value', type : 'string'}]  
});
```

Comment: what does your store and model config look like?

Comment: I have added them to my post.

Comment: As far as I remember idProperty is not store's property but model's so consider moving it there and with that you're returning two id_metric's with the same value so it does not seem to be unique. Additionally you can shorten the code `Ext.getStore('MyStore').findRecord('id_metric', 1)`. Double check response with firebug or such, if there isn't any error like a problem with decoding. For now try dumping data in load's callback function because you might be retrieving them before they even get to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

What i don't get is the way you have used `myStore`. You have used it both ways as a string as well as a variable. Which is it? If its a string, then `myStore.load()` will not work. If its a variable, you need to lose the quotes on `Ext.StoreMgr.lookup(myStore)`. Where is the store variable being declared?

Comment: I have declared :

`var myStore = this.getMyStore();`

Comment: Have you created the store and model using Ext.create? From my understanding, these are just definitions, you need to create them once they have been defined.

Comment: I'm using the Extjs 4 MVC architecture, the store and model are defined then used by the controller. I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your using ajax request you can get **id_metric** ...just have a look at the success function.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'blabla.tml',
    method:POST,                                                                      
    params : {
        item : Data
    },
    success : function(response) {
        var res = response.responseText;                                                                        
        alert(Ext.decode(res));
        var jsonData = Ext.decode(res);
        var data = jsonData.data; // here data will contain ur data with root data.
```

You can load the data here now

```
    Ext.getStore('Mystore').loadData(data);                                             
    }
});
```

And you are using the mystore to load...is your Mystore's storeId:mystore,
just have a look at at it once.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be that you are confusing the store by having 2 objects with the same id.
(Your JSON code shows "id_metric":"1" twice).

Most likely however, the automatic conversion to the model fails.
Try doing:

```
var model = Ext.create("Metrics.model.MyModel", {"id_metric":"1","name_filter":"doc filter","type_guicomp":"combobox"});
```

to see what the model looks like and if it is able to create an instance.

If that works (so you are able to create a model), drill down in your store to see if the data is actually in there.
Look for this:

```
myStore.proxy.reader.jsonData
```

Also, as was pointed out in the comments, the idProperty is a model property, you should declare it in your model.